# Given array of hashes, how can I use select on one key of the hash while evaluating on another key?

Tags: ruby

With my array of hashes:

```
data = [{:bool => true, :val => 5}, {:bool => false, :val => 9}, {:bool => true, :val => 1}]
```

I would like to iterate through the data and retrieve an array of values only. I can do:

```
data.map{|x| x[:val] if x[:bool]}
```

which returns:

```
[5, nil, 1]
```

But this method requires an additional .compact call to get rid of the nil values.

Is there a better way of achieving this?

Comment: Are you sure that you use `select` and not `collect`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use chaining instead to first [`select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-select) only those where `:bool` is `true`, then [`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-map) the results to `:val`:

```
data.select { |h| h[:bool] }.map { |h| h[:val] }  #=> [5, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

`data.map { |x| x[:val] if x[:bool] }.compact` is probably the easiest to read, but you can go down to one function call via `reduce`:

```
data.reduce([]) { |m,x| m << x[:val] if x[:bool]; m }
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem an elegant way but you can try this:

```
data = [{:bool => true, :val => 5}, {:bool => false, :val => 9}, {:bool => true, :val => 1}]
result = Array.new
data.each do |b|
val = Hash.try_convert(b)[:val]
result.unshift(val)
end
```